# How to create a program that converts 1 dll file into another dll file?

Tags: c#, file, dll, filesystems

So I want to make a mod installer that doesn't contain any game code but still installs the full modded dll. Everyone with the official game always starts with the same dll (written in C# and unity).

My initial idea was to decompile using ILspy (as we only have access to .dlls) and recompile but that doesn’t work (build errors). I have thought about using something like winMerge to save changes between .dlls but not 100% sure how to use it and my final idea is to convert the whole binary from storred file into a normal number and find the difference between the 2 files.

Anyone have any idead of whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: If ILSpy produces invalid code and the original assembly was not obfuscated, that's a bug in ILSpy. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: It happend with all decompilers, its one of the advanced 3d graphics renderers built into the game that produces invalid decompiled code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It been a while but i want to get back to how i solved this. I ended up making an installer that compares the different in hash (binary) between 2 binary files and creates a patch. Now this patch can then be applied in the installer itself to make the output dll! Here is the github if anyone is interested - https://github.com/dan771/Snowtopia-Mod-Installer

Comment: You will discover in the end that stacking mods on top of each other doesn't work very well because of binary offsets in the dll.

Comment: Yea luckily we only have 1 version of mods with everything configurable inside to turn things on / off which is handy. For updates plan in the future will just be to include uninstaller that saves some data like user presets etc. And then just reinstall using new updated patch.

Answer (score 0):

My best luck has come from `ildasm` / `patch` / `ilasm`. You can do essentially the same thing with `Mono.Cecil`. It's quite automatable even in the face of an obfuscated dll provided that the original dll has no native code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! Do u have any tips on how to use Mono.Cecil for this kind of thing and creating a script to put into a installer?

Comment: @danMan771: It's enormous. There's not much I can truly give you until you've done it once. Make a toy example work, then we can discuss it.

Comment: I solved it! Take a look at my answer